# call javascript function from different class (& module?) file once data loaded

Tags: javascript, function, class, callback

Fairly new to js classes and webpack any pointers for the below much appreciated.

I don't have to pass the callback function as a variable but thought it would be straight forward to do.

app.js

```
import { abcMap } from "./js/d3";
import { abcContent } from "./js/abcContent";

//styles
import "./scss/main.scss";
import "./css/style.css";

// want to call this from abcMap
var abc = new abcContent({
  map_tgt: "#vis",
  marker_selector: ".location-marker",
});

//
var mapParams = {
  mapFile: "./data/world-regions-countries-110m.geo.json",
  markers: "./data/locations-latlng.csv",
  tgt: "#vis",
  callbackOnDataLoad : abc.toCall() // 
};
var map = new abcMap(mapParams);
map.callbackOnDataLoad = toCall();
console.log(map);
var map_markers;
```

abcContent.js

```
export function abcContent(params) {
  var elements;
  var windowHeight;
  var activeAreaHeight = 600;
  var activeAreaTop;

  function toCall() {
    console.log("called!");
  }
 }
```

abcMap.js

```
  export function abcMap(params) {

  d3csv(params.markers).then(function (locations) {
    addLocations(locations);
    //params.callbackOnDataLoad here. ie toCall()
  });
  
 }
```

Comment: `import { abcContent } from "./js/abcContent";` in `"./js/d3";`?

Comment: You shouldn't call the function you're trying to pass, `callbackOnDataLoad: abc.toCall`
and inside `abcMap.js`, shouldn't it be `params.callbackOnDataLoad() // i.e toCall()`. Probably, I'm missing something?

Comment: maybe start simple - how can I just call 'toCall()' from the other class and file?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava so tried that.  but no joy. import { abcContent } from "./abcContent";
// const callMe = irgcContent.checkPosition;
abcContent.checkPosition();  'd3.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: _irgcContent__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.irgcContent.checkPosition is not a function
    at Module../src/js/d3.js (d3.js:5)'

Comment: What's this `irgcContent`? Isn't mentioned anywhere in your question

Comment: It’s actually abc